# How to convert an array of keys to an object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I want to convert this:

```
let arr = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
```

To this:

```
let obj = { a: null, b: null, c: null };
```

Thank you :)

Comment: What have you tried? I suggest you give [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) a try, eg `arr.reduce((obj, key) => ({...obj, [key]: null}), {})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
console.log(
    Object.fromEntries(['a', 'b', 'c'].map(x => ([x, null])))
);
```

Comment: Instead of spoon-feeding code to the asker, please consider *explaining* how the code you've answered will help to solve the asker's question.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [object entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) to get the desired results you are after.

**Demo:**

```js
let arr = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

let conv = Object.fromEntries(arr.map(y => ([y, null])))

console.log(conv)
```